# UIBezierPath from UIImage removing transparent pixels

Tags: ios, uiimage, uibezierpath, gpuimage, edge-detection

Input [image: Image With transparent background]

Output:
[image: Bezier Path]

Given an UIImage with transparent background, I want to calculate bezier path for image excluding transparent pixels ? (like in output image dotted path you can see)

Is there any best way to achieve this?

I have one solution:
1. Detect edge using GPUImage with 1.0 precision - image1
2. Detect edge using GPUImage with 2.0 precision - image2
3. image3 = image2 - image1.
4. iterate through each pixels and where ever dark point found just put that coordinate in bezier path.

What could be better solution ?